# Where is the org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.StandardOutputStreamLog?

Tags: java, junit4

Where is this class?
My project use the JUnit 4.12, and not found the StandardOutputStreamLog.
Is it be removed at this release?
or it come from the other lib? and what is the relation between these tow?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This class is deprecated and you should use [SystemOutRule](https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/apidocs/org/junit/contrib/java/lang/system/SystemOutRule.html).

Check the [source](https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/apidocs/org/junit/contrib/java/lang/system/StandardOutputStreamLog.html)

> StandardOutputStreamLog()
>
> **Deprecated.**
>
> Please use new SystemOutRule().enableLog().
>
> Creates a rule that records writes while they are still written to the
>   standard output stream.

Answer (score 13):

`SystemOutRule` superseded `StandardOutputStreamLog` as suggested by @Rahul Tripathi.

Just adding few more pointers to get started right away.

Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
    <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Add the jar to the buildpath to get the below import.

```
import org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.SystemOutRule;

public void MyTest {
    @Rule
    public final SystemOutRule systemOutRule = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();

    @Test
    public void writesTextToSystemOut() {
        System.out.print("hello world");
        assertEquals("hello world", systemOutRule.getLog());
    }
}
```

Reference: http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/

Answer (score 6):

StandardOutputStreamLog() is not deprecated. It's a class that's not present in the JUnit 4.x package. I google this class plus the word maven like so : org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.StandardOutputStreamLog() + maven and I found that it is not define in the junit Maven Repository but instead in the com.github.stefanbirkner. So by adding the maven coordinate

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
    <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You should be able to resolve the problem.

Comment: It is deprecated as stated in previous comments - you'll find 'Deprecated - Please use SystemOutRule' info in StandardOutputStramLog JavaDoc. Full information how you can include this library in different way is here [link](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/download.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you use gradle, you can add the following dependency rules in your *build.gradle* file.

```
dependencies {
testCompile "com.github.stefanbirkner:system-rules:${systemRulesVersion}"}
```

You should be able to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to also import the stefanbirkner:system-rules library following implementing JUnit tests and experiencing error:

```bash
java: package org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system does not exist
```

I am using Maven in IntelliJ so the steps I took were:

1. From File menu select project structure
   [image: screenshot1]
2. In Project Structure screen select libraries and plus sign in left pane to add new lib from Maven
   [image: screenshot2]
3. search for stefanbirkner:system-rules and ok
   [image: screenshot3]
4. Select module where library to be imported and ok then apply and ok on Project Structure screen
   [image: screenshot4]
5. On import statement right click to show context options
   [image: screenshot5]
6. add library to class path
   [image: screenshot6]
7. add the dependency in pom.xml

```html
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
        <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshot. In that case, you should edit your answer and provide the content of the last screenshot as a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) that other users can actually easily copy-paste if they need to.

Comment: @Antoine thanks . I've put in edit but not sure if is correct to use the snippet.

Comment: Despite the steps above solving the problem for the local build, when I ran 'mvn verify' I came across problem that despite having imported the class it had failed to add it to the classpath. So if you still experience problems make sure the imported libs have been added to classpath -can check your classpath  using System.getProperty("java.class.path") .  I had to do cleanup of the libraries, deleting downloads from .m2 directory as well. Make sure no superfluous libraries installed as this also caused some problems.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too, the fact is that the library JUnit 4.12 don't have the package `org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system`. The library that you need is system-rules. For to solve this, you can search on google "system-rules Junit" and then found the links for to download the library. For example now is available to download in this [link](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/)

I hope this will help to someone.